# How do you create a Locator in Protractor that uses OR logic?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

We have a table in a web app that is conceptually like this:

```
<list>
  <list-item>
    <span>Name:</span>
    <div>John</div>
  </list-item>
  ... goes on with repeated list-items with span's and div's ...
</list>
```

Is it possible to do something like `element.all(by.tagName('span') OR by.tagName('div'))` ? I just want to extract the elements of this into a dictionary where the element in the span is the Key and the element in the div is value. Then assert that the row values match expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for [`.map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var listItems = $$("list list-item").map(function (listItem) {
    return listItem.element("span").getText().then(function (label) {
        return listItem.element("div").getText().then(function (value) {
            return {
               label: value
            };
        });
    });
});

listItems.then(function (values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

`values` would be an array of objects.